# Loop without Do error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to implement a simple Newton's method iterative solver using Excel VB (I have never used VB.)

I keep getting the error `loop without a Do` and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to find the roots of the function `z^3 - z^2 - (B^2 + B - A)z - A*B` called the compressibility factor.

My source [MSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx)

```
Function zCalculation(ByVal temp As Double, ByVal press As Double) As Double

Dim tempCr As Double
Dim pressCr As Double
Dim A As Double
Dim B As Double

tempCr = temp / 238.5

pressCr = press / 547.424092

A = pressCr / tempCr
A = A / (9 * (2 ^ (1 / 3) - 1))
B = pressCr / tempCr
B = B * (2 ^ (1 / 3) - 1) / 3



Dim zNot As Double
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0
zNot = 1#

Do
    counter = counter + 1

    zNot = zNot - (zNot ^ 3 - zNot ^ 2 - (B ^ 2 + B - A) * zNot - A * B) / (3 * zNot ^ 2 - 2 * zNot - (B ^ 2 + B - A))
    If counter > 1000 Then
       Exit Do

Loop Until eval(zNot, A, B) < 0.000001


zCalculation = zNot


End Function
```

break

```
Function eval(ByVal z As Double, ByVal A As Double, ByVal B As Double) As Double

    eval = z ^ 3 - z ^ 2 - (B ^ 2 + B - A) * z - A * B

End Function
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need an:

```
End If
```

in your code.

Comment: cant believe I actually searched on stackoverflow before checking this

Comment: I had the same problem! I feel embarrassed! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 Function zCalculation(ByVal temp As Double, ByVal press As Double) As Double

  Dim tempCr As Double
  Dim pressCr As Double
  Dim A As Double
  Dim B As Double

  tempCr = temp / 238.5

  pressCr = press / 0.546789

  A = pressCr / tempCr
  A = A / (9 * (2 ^ (1 / 3) - 1))
  B = pressCr / tempCr
  B = B * (2 ^ (1 / 3) - 1) / 3



  Dim zNot As Double
  Dim counter As Integer
  counter = 0
  zNot = 1#

  Do
      counter = counter + 1

      zNot = zNot - (zNot ^ 3 + zNot ^ 2 - (B ^ 2 + B - A) * zNot - A * B) / (3 * zNot ^ 2 + 2 * zNot - (B ^ 2 + B - A))
      If counter > 1000 Then
         Exit Do
      End if  ' <--- Here

  Loop Until eval(zNot, A, B) < 0.000001

  zCalculation = zNot
 End Function
```

Comment: although you had it correct as well Gary posted first.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub datacalculationsandformat()
Dim row As Integer
row = 2
Do While Cells(row, 2) <> ""
Cells(row, 3).Value = Cells(row, 2).Value * 0.3
Cells(row, 4).Value = Cells(row, 2) * 0.1
Cells(row, 5).Value = Cells(row, 2).Value + Cells(row, 3).Value + Cells(row, 4).Value
If Cells(row, 5).Value >= 8000 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 5).Font.Bold = True
row = row + 1
Loop
```